# Print js file Yii2

Tags: javascript, php, yii2

Is there any way to print js file? 
I know I can use `register` method of `AssetBundle` class to register a js/css file into page, also there is another option: to store javascript code in a php variable and use the following method:

`\yii\web\View::registerJs($js, \yii\web\View::POS_READY);`

But what I need is (on server-side) open a js file, get the contents and write down the code into the html.

The meaning of doing so is that the javascript code is needed only in one page, but also I don't want to add extra requests on client-side.

Also, I know, I can use php `include` method to load the file and store into a variable, but maybe there is a Yii-way.

So, is there any proper way to do so ? Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this , I hope this will Help you.

```
<?php 

$this->registerJs(' 
$(document).ready(function(){
 $(\'.ordinary\').hide(); 
 $(\'.special\').hide();
 $(\'#company-typeofcompany\').change(function () {
     var x = $(this).val();
     if (x === "ordinary") {
         $(\'.ordinary\').show();  
         $(\'.special\').hide();
     } else {
         $(\'.special\').show();
         $(\'.ordinary\').hide(); 
     }
 });

  });', \yii\web\View::POS_READY);

  ?>
```

Thank You..